# How do I get a named range to appear on another sheet?

Tags: excel, range, named

I am trying to duplicate a named range on a different worksheet but I am having problems making it work.

- On Sheet1, `A3:A92` (90 cells) is a named range, "Employees"
- On Sheet2, I want to duplicate the named range, "Employees" such that when values in the named range change on Sheet1 it is updated on Sheet2.
- On Sheet2, I also want new entries that expand the range beyond the current 90 cells to appear on Sheet2

On Sheet2, I have tried: `='Employees'!A1"` and then dragged the formula down until it fill 90 cells.

I also tried entering `=Employees` in `A1` and hit <kbd>enter</kbd> but I get `#VALUE!`

If I use and array formula `{=Employees}` on `A2` I get the correct entry for the first row of the named range but when I drag it down, it just repeats the first entry in the named range.

Is there are solution to this problem? What is the best approach?

Comment: For the "=employees" approach, you'd have to select the 90 cells first and use ctrl, shift and enter to confirm the formula. But why do you need to duplicate the list?

Comment: Yeah that's what I have been playing with.  I wanted it to be dynamic so that if my named range grew it would expand with it and always reference the named range

Comment: In future questions, please work on making the question clearer and more concise. It was difficult to understand without multiple reads. I would also strongly encourage the use of images of (example) raw data and an example of what you want the output to look like. This will make it easier to answer and get a quicker responses. I personally almost left this question because it was hard to determine 
 what you were asking. Good layout makes it easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks @Brian, it makes it looks nicer alright and more legible.  I was unsure how to format it as my keyboard differs but I note the advice.  Also, in work some sites are blocked so the image uploads can be difficult.

Comment: As for posting images, you should be able to post them directly on stackoverflow by clicking the image icon at  the top of your post. Unless your ISP blocks imgur, it should post. When you said, "I was unsure how to format...," were you referring to formatting your questions or conditionally formatting the what I posted in the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments of you and SJR, On the second worksheet, select more cells than the 90 that currently exist to create a margin for growth and enter the array formula `=Employees`

[image]

If you want to make the `#N/A` errors to "disappear," use conditional formatting. This way, you have room for growth built in and it still appears "pretty."